# Is there a way to tell resharper to ignore a specific method name for an entire solution?

Tags: c#, resharper

Basically, I'm looking for similar functionality to their [UsedImplicitly] annotation, but I have a set of method names/signatures I want to apply it to across the entire solution, and would rather not use annotations all over the place.

I'm using VS2015 with Resharper 10 on a project in Unity3D. For those not familiar, Unity3D allows you to inherit from one of their provided classes to allow the class you write to be attached to objects that will exist in worldspace within the engine. Your code then ties into the inherited classes functionality via a series of lifecycle methods related to the inherited class (Awake(), Start(), Update(), etc).

Unfortunately, due to legacy (poor) design decisions, Unity doesn't expose these methods as virtual or via an interface, but instead use a technique similar to reflection at runtime to locate your codes lifecycle method definitions. These means at design time, there are no direct references to these methods, R# is marking them as unused.

So far, the only options I can find are to always annotate each method (pollutes the codebase with tons of annotations since these methods are declared quite frequently), always mark them as public (a workable solution, but not always ideal, and goes against Unity3D conventions), or just deal with the false positives Resharper throws.

Ideally what I want to be able to do is configure something in R# settings to say "methods with this name  should always be marked as UsedImplicitly" or something similar. Thus far though I haven't found a way to do this. Any suggestions would be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to get ReSharper to do this for a generic codebase, but there is a ReSharper extension for Unity which will do what you want. It recognises classes that derive from `MonoBehaviour` and marks the appropriate methods as in use. There are currently outstanding pull requests to support more methods, I hope to get those merged and released soon.

Go to ReSharper → Extension Manager and search for "Unity".

Comment: Perfect, I'll check that out today. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question: How do the classes get marked? I'm not the only developer on this project and the other dev / our build server don't currently have a resharper license, so I can't use Annotations (ideally, I'd like to avoid checking in resharper comments as well, but that's not as big of a deal)

Comment: Seems I can't edit comments just yet...but I tried it out and this plugin is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for the tip

Comment: The plugin runs a piece of code that directly tells ReSharper that the methods should not be marked as unused. You can [see it here](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/blob/master/src/resharper-unity/UsageInspectionsSuppressor.cs). I'm also going to introduce external annotations, which add the attribute annotations in an xml file that will suppress some more inspections automatically.